# How can I change my WLAN device's name?

Tags: networking, drivers, realtek

On my last Linux installation, my laptop's Intel/Realtek PXE wireless radio device had name, as seems to be common, `wlan0`. I like this name; it is nice to type and remember.

That was Linux Mint 14.04, which I've upgraded to Ubuntu 15.10. Now, the same radio has name `wlp2s0`, as reported by `ifconfig`. I imagine this is an update or change to either the kernel or the `rle*` Realtek driver since 14.04.

Is there a way I can change it back to `wlan0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter into the terminal:

```
sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

Change the `NAME` to whatever you want.

Easy day **=)**

**EDIT**: You can generate the `70-persistent-net.rules` file with `udevadm trigger`.

Comment: Wait, I have an `/etc/udev/rules.d/`, but it's an empty directory. Can you add to your answer a template for a rule that I can use to make a new file?

Comment: I'm always thrown by the `you can accept this answer in 3 minutes` :)

Comment: @cat edit made - does it work for you?

Comment: I ran it as root but `/etc/udev/rules.d` is still an empty directory.

Comment: @cat `udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=net` ?

Comment: Still empty. Is there perhaps another location for `rules.d`?

Comment: do you have `udev` installed?

Comment: This can also generate it: `/lib/udev/write_net_rules all_interfaces`

Comment: You may also need to reboot

Comment: I have `udev` installed, yes, and I have a `/bin/udevadm`. I'll try that command, but I won't reboot right now.

Comment: `stat: cannot stat ‘/lib/udev/write_net_rules’: No such file or directory`

Comment: @cat you should probably unaccept this answer, to notify other users that this isn't solved, because I have no idea why it's not working...

Comment: I rebooted; nothing has changed, the dir is empty as before.

Comment: @cat you could a bounty to your question...

Comment: I would if my system were unusable.

Comment: ditto on my ubuntu - have udevadm, have the directory, directory is empty, write_net_rules non-existent. no "persistent-net" found anywhere on the filesystem with locate, but there is another rules.d folder in /lib/udev - grep'ing for the name of my wifi interface finds no files containing the name displayed with ifconfig.